# Is it possible to run tests in Gitlab without adding Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Consider having a project on GitLab with working unit tests: can we run the tests without adding a Kubernetes cluster to project? Because when I want to enable Auto DevOps I am  urged to create a Kubernetes cluster!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible and you are not forced to use Kubernetes. There's a plethora of solutions to be found on the [CI/CD-documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/index.html).